# Show dynamic dropdown list, with jQuery, based on selected value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a a drop down list based on the earlier selection. It does not work. It  gives me all the values that are listed.  ticket_fields_21114185 is my 1st drop down list that has values like [desktop, web browser]. ticket_fields_21108325 is my 2nd drop down list that has all the other values listed.

```
 $j(document).ready(function() {  
   var ren
   var dtop = ['windows_7'];
   var webrow= ['all','chrome','ie'];  

   //this builds the dropdown list  
   Buildoptions = {      
     selected: function(value, name){    
       return '<option value="'+value+'" selected="selected">'+name+'</option>';     
     },     
     notselected: function(value, name){    
       return '<option value="'+value+'">'+name+'</option>';  
     },      
     clear: function(){    
       return '<option value=""></option>'; 
     } 
   } 
   //goes through the selected array and builds the options  
   var makeSelection = function(theField, theArray) {      
     for ( x = 0; x < theArray.length; x++ ) {              
     console.log('makeing select ' + theArray)         
     if (x == 0)         
        $j(''+ theField +'').append(Buildoptions.notselected(theArray[x], theArray[x]));              

     } 
   }  

   $j('select#ticket_fields_21114185').change( function(){

     ren=$j('select#ticket_fields_21114185 option:selected').val();

     if(ren=='desktop'){
       makeSelection('select#ticket_fields_21108325',dtop);
     }
     else
       makeSelection('select#ticket_fields_21108325',webrow)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's nothing but your last else statement has no brackets {}
Possibly it triggers both selections when desktop is selected
Diving in your code for a closer look now so if this aint it don't give your hopes up yet ! :)

Edit : after looking into your code i have more questions then answers.
To make things a bit easyer could you paste your html as well(although i think i can handle making 2 selects).
If i understand correctly your second select should display some  dynamic data depending on the first select.
I made the following conclusions :

- Your code misses a few ; here and there after each statement.
- You're also lacking a clear function to remove the values of the
  dynamic select before adding new functions.
- Your for loop with the array is weird to me, why x+2 and not +1? It looks like the code wants to use the first value in the array as the value and the second as the name. But your list only has 3 values not 6?

Is it possible that you copy pasted the code and as of now it is adding a value and undefined to the dynamic select after each selection change of the static select?

Comment: Made few changes to make selection function and it works now. The code includes the changes. Thanks